# Haskell - Could not deduce ... from Context error - OpenGL AsUniform class type

Tags: class, haskell, opengl, types, uniform

I'm working on making my data types general instead of taking in the OpenGL type `GLfloat`. So I started making it take in type `a` and then just replacing everything with that.

Now, I've come to a point where I'm setting uniform variables, but they take in GLfloat's. I'm using a library called GLUtil which makes it a bit easier, which has provided a class `AsUniform`, to check whether the type can be a uniform variable or not. I stick it in my type signature, but it stills gives me an error. Here's the code:

```
-- | Sets the modelview and projection matrix uniform variables.
mvpUnif :: (GL.UniformComponent a, Num a, Epsilon a, Floating a, AsUniform a) => (GLState a) -> ShaderProgram  -> IO ()
mvpUnif state p = do
-- Check if view and projection matrices are there, else set them to the identity.
let vMat = case vMatrix state of
    Just v -> v
    Nothing -> getIdentity
let pMat = case pMatrix state of
    Just p -> p
    Nothing -> getIdentity
-- Multiply model and view matrix together.
let mvMatrix = vMat !*! mMatrix state
setUniform p uModelViewMatrixVar mvMatrix
setUniform p uProjectionMatrixVar pMat
```

and the error:

```
Could not deduce (AsUniform (V4 (V4 a)))
  arising from a use of `setUniform'
from the context (GL.UniformComponent a,
                  Num a,
                  Epsilon a,
                  Floating a,
                  AsUniform a)
  bound by the type signature for
             mvpUnif :: (GL.UniformComponent a, Num a, Epsilon a, Floating a
,
                         AsUniform a) =>
                        GLState a -> ShaderProgram -> IO ()
  at src\Graphics\FreeD\Shaders\DefaultShaders.hs:194:12-119
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  setUniform p uModelViewMatrixVar mvMatrix
In the expression:
  do { let vMat = ...;
       let pMat = ...;
       let mvMatrix = vMat !*! mMatrix state;
       setUniform p uModelViewMatrixVar mvMatrix;
       .... }
In an equation for `mvpUnif':
    mvpUnif state p
      = do { let vMat = ...;
             let pMat = ...;
             let mvMatrix = ...;
             .... }
```

V4 is made an instance of AsUniform, as well as M44, which is a type for (V4 (V4 a)), which I thought might be the issue, so I'm not sure why it's acting up.

Here's the source for the class:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUtil-0.8.5/docs/Graphics-GLUtil-Linear.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-XFlexibleContexts` and the constraint, literally, to your existing answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

mvpUnif :: ( GL.UniformComponent a
           , Num a
           , Epsilon a
           , Floating a
           , AsUniform a
           , AsUniform (V4 (V4 a))
           ) => (GLState a) -> ShaderProgram  -> IO ()
```

Usually this is the routine for constraints that aren't inferrable, or where constraints need to be transitively included in all call sites. This happens to me all the time with `MonadState` et al. In this case, `setUniform` is the culprit.

Comment: Nope :/. Same error. Put it at the top and in my cabal file, and I tried changing the sig to `AsUniform (V4 (V4 a))`, but that didn't affect it. Maybe the GLUtil package page might shine a bit of light of why it wouldn't work, you think?